# Why doesn't flexbox and flex-flow make my cards move to the new column but it constantly shrinks them?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a problem with flexbox, it won't move my items to new row it just shrinks them constantly. I tried lot of things but it won't move it just shrinks it.
I removed CSS for parts that I think don't have to do anything with the problem like headers and etc.

```css
.store-row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 60vh;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-flow: wrap;
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  width: 320px;
  height: 480px;
  /* background: #191919; */
  border-radius: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 3%;
  flex-basis: 20%;
}

.card::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  transform: skewY(345deg);
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.card:hover::before {
  top: -70%;
  transform: skewY(390deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="store-row">
  <div class="card" id="netflix">
    <div class="imgBox">
      <img src="images/netflixlogo.png" class="mouse">
    </div>
    <div class="contentBox">
      <h3>NETFLIX PREMIUM 12 MESECI</h3>
      <h2 class="price">20.<small>00</small> €</h2>
      <a href="#" class="buy">Buy Now</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card" id="spotify">
    <div class="imgBox">
      <img src="images/spotify.png" class="mouse">
    </div>
    <div class="contentBox">
      <h3>SPOTIFY PREMIUM 12 MESECI</h3>
      <h2 class="price">15.<small>00</small> €</h2>
      <a href="#" class="buy">Buy Now</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card" id="nordvpn">
    <div class="imgBox">
      <img src="images/nordvpn.jpg" class="mouse">
    </div>
    <div class="contentBox">
      <h3>NORDVPN PREMIUM 12 MESECI</h3>
      <h2 class="price">10.<small>00</small> €</h2>
      <a href="#" class="buy">Buy Now</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So it appears that the cards _do_ wrap when I run your code. Could you describe more abut what you are hoping it will do?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove your `flex-basis: 20%;`  setting for `.card` - it contradicts the given `width` for these elements.

```css
.store-row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 60vh;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-flow: wrap;
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  width: 320px;
  height: 480px;
  background: #191919;
  border-radius: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 3%;
}

.card::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  transform: skewY(345deg);
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.card:hover::before {
  top: -70%;
  transform: skewY(390deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="store-row">
  <div class="card" id="netflix">
    <div class="imgBox">
      <img src="images/netflixlogo.png" class="mouse">
    </div>
    <div class="contentBox">
      <h3>NETFLIX PREMIUM 12 MESECI</h3>
      <h2 class="price">20.<small>00</small> €</h2>
      <a href="#" class="buy">Buy Now</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card" id="spotify">
    <div class="imgBox">
      <img src="images/spotify.png" class="mouse">
    </div>
    <div class="contentBox">
      <h3>SPOTIFY PREMIUM 12 MESECI</h3>
      <h2 class="price">15.<small>00</small> €</h2>
      <a href="#" class="buy">Buy Now</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card" id="nordvpn">
    <div class="imgBox">
      <img src="images/nordvpn.jpg" class="mouse">
    </div>
    <div class="contentBox">
      <h3>NORDVPN PREMIUM 12 MESECI</h3>
      <h2 class="price">10.<small>00</small> €</h2>
      <a href="#" class="buy">Buy Now</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```